# How to check all entries in an array of objects for two equal properties

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which I want to reduce and add a property. If two key/values are the same (name & size) the entries should be combined like the following:

The original array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1
    name: "foo",
    size: 4998,
    relatedId: 17,
    link: "https://www.google.com/"
  },
  {
    id: 2
    name: "foo",
    size: 4998,
    relatedId: 21,
    link: "https://www.google2.com/"
  },
  {
    id: 3
    name: "bar",
    size: 381,
    relatedId: 35,
    link: "https://www.google3.com/"
  },
  {
    id: 4
    name: "bar",
    size: 381,
    relatedId: 41,
    link: "https://www.google4.com/"
  },
  {
    id: 5
    name: "baz",
    size: 666,
    relatedId: 50,
    link: "https://www.google5.com/"
  },
]
```

And I want to generate the following output:

```
[
  {
    id: 1
    name: "foo",
    size: 4998,
    relatedId: 17,
    link: "https://www.google.com/",
    relations: [
      {
        id:1,
        relatedId: 17
      },
      {
        id:2,
        relatedId: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3
    name: "bar",
    size: 381,
    relatedId: 35,
    relations: [
      {
        id: 3,
        relatedId: 35
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        relatedId: 41
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5
    name: "baz",
    size: 666,
    relatedId: 50,
    relations: [
      {
        id: 5,
        relatedId: 50
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So the new property *relations* with the *id* and the *relatedId* should be added to the objects and if 2 or more objects have the same *name* and *size* the entries from the second on should be removed and the *id* and *relatedId* should be pushed to the *relations*.

I tried this but it doesn't work yet:

```
mergeDuplicates (fileArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
        fileArray[i].relations = []
        fileArray[i].relations .push({
            id: fileArray[i].id,
            relatedId: fileArray[i].relatedId,
        })
        for (let j = 1; j < fileArray.length; j++) {
            if (fileArray[i].name=== fileArray[j].name && fileArray[i].size === fileArray[j].size) {
                fileArray[i].relations .push({
                    id: fileArray[j].id,
                    relatedId: fileArray[j].relatedId,
                })
                fileArray.splice(j, 1)
            }
        }
    }

    return fileArray;
}
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: @NinaScholz I added my current function which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a map of the values, keyed on name and size.

Then we can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to return the final result:

```js
const input = [ { id: 1, name: "foo", size: 4998, relatedId: 17, link: "https://www.google.com/" }, { id: 2, name: "foo", size: 4998, relatedId: 21, link: "https://www.google2.com/" }, { id: 3, name: "bar", size: 381, relatedId: 35, link: "https://www.google3.com/" }, { id: 4, name: "bar", size: 381, relatedId: 41, link: "https://www.google4.com/" }, { id: 5, name: "baz", size: 666, relatedId: 50, link: "https://www.google5.com/" }, ] 

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Key our map using name and size 
    const key = cur.name + cur.size;
    // If nothing exists at the key, create a new one...
    acc[key] = acc[key] || { ...cur, relations: []};
    acc[key].relations.push({ id: cur.id, relatedId: cur.relatedId });
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log("Result:",result)
```

Comment: Wow thanks! It works and it is less code compared to my attempt.

Comment: Great, thanks for testing it. You can use a similar approach to group objects in general, just decide on a key and do whatever processing you need.